# Simple wireless file transfer?

Tags: bluetooth

I'm looking for a way to wirelessly transfer files a short distance without putting the computer 'on a network.'  We have industrial computers inside air-purged boxes for operation in a potentially explosive environment.  We have found 'intrinsically safe' keyboards to mount outside the box to allow the computer to be controlled, with monitor visible through a window.

The only piece missing now is a way to copy files to and from the system.

I see two possibilities:

1) Some kind of intrinsically safe USB connection on the outside of the box.  I haven't found this and don't think it could exist simply because when you're plugging in your flash drive, there is an exposed electrical connection which could cause a spark.

2) Some kind of wireless solution.  Ideally we just run a network cable out of the box, but a further restriction is that these computers can not be on a network for security reasons.  Is there a bluetooth or irDA flash drive of some sort?

Ideally I'd like to walk up to the box with a flash drive in my pocket, or held up to the window.  Have it automatically or manually mount as a drive, then drag files to/from the computer.

Comment: Try posting to controlsoverload.com as many industrial folks there

Comment: Wouldn't a USB bluetooth or infrared adapter pose the same electrical risk as a USB flash drive when connecting them to the host machine?

Comment: cross-posted to http://controlsoverload.com/questions/127/simple-wireless-file-transfer

Answer (score 1):

Seagate had a Bluetooth and WiFi drive.  Not sure if it still is available or...  Looks close to what you need.

[Seagate DAVE](http://www.dlink.com/products/?pid=377)

Toshiba had the Bluetooth Pocket Server but it may be discontinued

For 802.11b or g D-Link makes an enclosure.  More range and installing a card should not be a big deal.

[DSM-G600](http://www.dlink.com/products/?pid=377)

Comment: I can't find a way to buy something like this, though it sounds close.  There's also something called the Agere BluOnyx but this might not exist anymore either.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing to do might be to get an intrinsically-safe cell phone with blue tooth and use that for the file-transfer.  Here are [some possibilities](http://www.intrinsically-safe-instruments.com/intrinsically-safe-cell-phones.html).